# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar el nombre a partir de una id de una tabla relacionada en laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, phpmyadmin, tablas, vistas

Estoy haciendo un sistema de inventarios con laravel 9, y tengo una tabla 'categorias' que está asociada a una tabla 'productos' ya que estos entran dentro de las categorías que uno cree. El id de la categoría se guarda en el producto y yo lo que quiero es que en el index donde se muestren los datos, en vez de mostrar el número del id de la categoría me muestre el nombre.

Modelo Producto

```
 public function categorias(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Categoria::class, 'id');
    }
```

Modelo Categoria

```
public function productos(){
        return $this->hasMany(Producto::class, 'id_cat');
    }
```

ProductoController

```
public function index()
    {
        $categorias = Categoria::all();
        $productos = Producto::with('categorias')->get();
        
        return view('producto.index', compact('categorias','productos')); //->with('productos',$productos);
    }
```

Vista

```
<table id="productos" class="table table-striped table-dark table-bordered shadow-lg nt-4">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">ID</th>
                <th scope="col">Imagen</th>
                <th scope="col">Código</th>
                <th scope="col">Categoría</th>
                <th scope="col">Descripción</th>
                <th scope="col">Stock</th>
                <th scope="col">Solicitado</th>
                <th scope="col">Acciones</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach ($productos as $producto)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$producto->id}}</td>
                <td>{{$producto->imagen}}</td>
                <td>{{$producto->codigo}}</td>
                <td>{{$producto->categoria->categoria}}</td>
                <td>{{$producto->descripcion}}</td>
                <td>{{$producto->cantidad}}</td>
                <td>{{$producto->solicitudes}}</td>
                <td>
                    <form action="{{route ('productos.destroy',$producto->id)}}" method="POST">
                        <a href="/productos/{{ $producto->id}}/edit" class="btn btn-info">Editar</a>
                        @csrf
                        @method('DELETE')
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Borrar</button>
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
                
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

En mi ignorancia, entiendo que lo que está mal sería

```
<td>{{$producto->categoria->categoria}}</td>
```

porque realmente no hay una 'categoria' en productos, pero no sé cómo hacer para que del `id_cat = categoria.id` me tome el nombre de la categoría, el error que me da es el siguiente:

```
Attempt to read property "categoria" on null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando se realiza una relación dentro de los modelos de cada tabla se les asigna un nombre a la funcion para poder ser utilizadas en otro momento

En tu caso el nombre de la relación que intentas consultar es `categorias`

Eso se ve aqui

```
 public function categorias(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Categoria::class, 'id');
    }
```

Luego para poder utilizar esa relación dentro de una consulta se utiliza `->with(nombre_relacion)`

Y efectivamente estas llamando a la funcion categorias, eso se ve aqui

```
 $productos = Producto::with('categorias')->get();
```

Tu unico error esta aqui

```
$producto->categoria->categoria
```

Ya que la llamada correcta seria `'la variable que hace la consulta' -> 'el nombre de la funcion que crea la relación' -> 'el nombre del campo de esa tabla relacionada que deseas consultar'`, quedando de la siguiente manera, tomando en cuenta que en tu tabla categorias hay un campo llamado categoria

```
$producto->categorias->categoria
```

En pocas palabras solo te comiste la `s` pero es bueno desglosar el porque del error

EDIT-------------------------

```
//se supone que la funcion categorias que permite la relacion se encuentra
//dentro del modelo producto, por lo llamo al modelo Categoria
//le indico que el campo id_cat debe coincidir con los registros del campo id de Categoria
//Con esto no olvides los pasos de más arriba
 public function categorias(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Categoria::class, 'id_cat', 'id');
    }
```

Comment: hi, le coloqué la 's' que me comí, pero de igual forma me da el error
Attempt to read property "categoria" on null

¿podría ser otra cosa?

Comment: Dentro de la tabla categorias existe un campo llamado categoria? normalmente uno coloca Nombre

Comment: sí, ¿sugieres que la cambie por "nombre?

Comment: No, esperate es que alli hay un error, se supone que la tabla productos contiene un ca,po llamada id_cat? que corresponde al id de la categoria?

Comment: id_cat es lo que me conecta esa tabla a la categoría. mi idea era que me trajera el nombre de la categoría cuando id_cat en la tabla productos fuera igual al id de la tabla categoría, ¿me explico?

Comment: Si la tabla productos contiene un campo llamado id_cat que corresponde al id de la categoria, entonces dentro de la relación estas haciendo mal la consulta en la función de categorias modifica esto ```belongsTo(Categoria::class, 'id');``` por ```belongsTo('App\Models\categorias (o el nombre que tenga el modelo categorias, recuerda mayusculas y minusculas)', 'id_cat', 'id');```

Comment: O ve el edit que realice

Comment: Sí me sirvió, de verdad muchísimas gracias :)

Comment: Por favor no olvides marcar la respuesta como correcta